# ATtiny85 not working at all

Tags: microcontroller, attiny, attiny85, blink

I am using an Arduino to program my ATtiny85 like in [this tutorial](http://highlowtech.org/?p=1695).

I am trying to make a simple blink example, here's the code:

```
    void setup() {
      pinMode(0, OUTPUT);
    }

    void loop() {
      digitalWrite(0, HIGH);
      delay(1000);
      digitalWrite(0, LOW);
      delay(1000);
    }
```

Connected to my programmer (which has a LED connected to pin 0) the LED flashes. When I plug it into my circuit it does not work (the LED stays on).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f311XK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Please tell me if the tags don't make sense (I am very new).

Comment: **A:** Try changing the delay(1000) to delay(1). **B:** switch place with the HIGH and LOW in the code. If you can see that it blinks or is more dim after doing **A** then there's something wrong with the clock divider.  If it still stays on after doing **A** then there's something else weird going on. If it still stays on after doing **B** then there's something wrong happening before it enters the loop part of the code.

Comment: Hi. Just edited the circuit for easy viewing. Have you tried adding 470nF cap to Gnd at the Reset pin?

Comment: Do you have access to an oscilloscope? Multimeter?

Comment: _When connected to my programmer it works, when I plug it into my circuit it doesn't work._ From this line I'd be more inclined to say there is a mistake/error in your circuit as opposed to the ATTiny85 itself.

Comment: @HarrySvensson The light stays on at full power for **A** and **B**.

Comment: @JasonHan I tried that, and it does nothing, thanks for trying though.

Comment: @pipe I have a multimeter, and poking around does not show anything out of the ordinary.

Comment: @Doodle I thought the same, but this circuit is quite simple, so I am 99% sure that my wiring is the same as the diagram above, which is why I added it above, but seeing as nobody has said anything about the circuit (except adding the 470nF cap), I think it should work.

Comment: Measure pin 0, what voltage did you get? Use DC mode.

Comment: @JasonHan he will read 5V. Otherwise the LED wouldn't light up. @ Nedla2004, if it stays on at full power for **A** and **B** then there's something else **MUCH** wrong. Take a picture of your setup. And what exactly are you using to upload to the ATTiny? (Is it an Arduino in programmer mode? Or an actual programmer?) Are you _sure_ you're uploading to the ATTiny?

Comment: Is there really no bypass capacitor at all anywhere in your circuit? This is one key difference between the device programmer and your circuit (as shown). Add a 0.1uF ceramic capacitor, with the leads trimmed as short as practical, across the VCC and GND, right at the ATtiny85. You won't see the problem with a multimeter, but there are switching current surges as any digital chip operates, and without a local bypass capacitor, those switching currents produce significant variation in the power supply voltage (at the device pins). Possibly enough to disrupt normal operation.

Answer (score 1):

> Connected to my programmer (which has a LED connected to pin 0) the LED flashes. When I plug it in to my circuit it does not work (the LED stays on.)

That alone tells you a lot about your problem. It suggest that your chip is successfully programmed and the issue is with your circuit.

Comment: @dannf I thought the same, but this circuit is quite simple, so I am 99% sure that my wiring is the same as the diagram above, which is why I added it above, but seeing as nobody has said anything about the circuit (except adding the 470nF cap), I think it should work.

Comment: What you you use for a 5V source? Have you checked if the power is clean?

Comment: @dannyf I am actually using the programmer itself, as I know that works well.